# Rewording commit deep in log

Tags: git, rebase

once again I am coming for your help. Namely I have a problem that I need to reword a git commit which is hidden deep in the git history.

Here is the deal. There is a commit A somewhere deep in history ( like 300 commits before HEAD ), after which lots of merges happened. I want to reword commit A, without rebasing it onto HEAD, and I want to preserve all the merges and all other commits.

I have tried rebasing the commit using git --interactive A^ , but this option puts out a ton of commits to be changed, which would not be as bad if it did not try to linearize the history. I tried git --interactive --onto A^ A^ A, and while this does reword a single commit only, it also leads to history which looks like:

HEAD - A^ - A

This means that the A and parent of A get rebased onto HEAD, which is exactly what I do not want. What I want is to perform very local change of single commit, and to leave this commit exactly where it is in git history.

Can this be done?

Comment: You *can* do this with the newfangled `--rebase-merges` option to `git rebase` (requires a new enough Git), but IMO that's harder than using `git replace` followed by `git filter-branch`. Since all the hash IDs from the reworded commit onward change (regardless of how you achieve it), this particular kind of thing is usually a bad idea: it's only OK if you're sure *everyone* with a clone of the repository is willing to abandon their existing commits in favor of the new improved ones.

Comment: All of the commits are local, so changing that is not a problem. As you see the plan is to not change the history at all just a single commit. Now the catch 22 is the fact that almost 99% of the commits which bother me are the commits which were merged into my local branch. Could you explain the usage of replace and filter-branch? Maybe that is exactly what I need.

Comment: In this case, run `git replace --edit <hash>` and modify the commit message. Git will insert a drop-in replacement, which works by Git noticing that there *is* a replacement, and showing that instead of the original. Replacement commits don't copy on clone, so someone who clones the repository sees only the original commit.

Comment: To fix this "doesn't copy on clone" property, you can run a no-op filter-branch: tell it not to change anything at all. It still obeys replacements by default, though, so as it copies the entire repository, it swaps in the replacement commit at the right point. From then on, all the copies use the new-and-improved chain-being-built-so-far, so that the end result is a repository in which all the original "bad" commits (the one with the wrong message, and everything downstream) has been copied to a new-and-improved "good" one.

Comment: (You don't *have* to do the filter-branch part at all, if you're OK with the not-copying-on-clone thing.)

Comment: The replace command does not do what I want. I need a real commit to be there. This maybe does create a replacement, but when I try to push the text I added to commit is still not visible to git server. Core of my problem is that a specific text has to be included in every git commit in order to be accepted by server, I am not trying to rewrite a very old commit.

Comment: As I said, replacements do not copy across clones (well, not by default). You will need to cement the replacement into place. ("across clones" is shorthand here: clone means fetch, and both fetch and push by default do not transfer replacement objects.)

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: "To fix this "doesn't copy on clone" property" ... see above :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `git replace --edit $commit_you_want_to_change` to reword the commit message. Exit the editor and the commit will be used as a replacement.

To make the replacment permanent, run `git filter-branch` without any filters:

```
git filter-branch -- --all
```

This will rewrite all of your history starting from your replaced commit. Older commit hashes will remain unchanged, but everything after the replaced commit will get new commit hashes.